# How can I increase the max number of clipboard slots that tmux has?

Tags: tmux

In `tmux`, we can see a list of recently copied items using the command `Prefix + =`. Unfortunately, this list truncates at 20 items for me, and my web searches were unable to find the option to increase the number of items beyond 20.

Is there an option that can be set in `.tmux.conf` to set the maximize number of items that can be held?

Alternately, is it possible to tag a particular entry as sticky so they will never be replaced for the lifetime of a session?

Answer (score 1):

After some more failed searching, I discovered the answer the old-fashioned way, by reading the source.

The option is called `buffer-limit` and it specifies the number of items that can be kept in the clipboard.

It is defined in `options-table.c` with a default value of 20 in `tmux 1.8`.
It is used in the function `window_copy_copy_buffer` inside `window-copy.c`.